# What's the meaning of "the one to beat"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, dictionaries

source: "Merriam-Webster's Vocabulary Builder" (Second Edition) P586

> nonpareil
>
> ...
>
> Critics seem to agree that this is the new nonpareil of video-game consoles, *the one to beat*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently the best product (or person) in its field. If you want to be the best, this is the one you would have to beat.